# Current working calculated field formula need to add ORs

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have been using the following calculated field formula which has worked great but I have been giver a new wrinkle....

=IF(AND(status_finance="complete",status_cnl="complete",status_solution="complete",status_hr="complete"),"complete","initial")

now I need to mark complete if 
 status_finance = complete and status_cnl = complete and status_solution = complete or N/A and status_hr = complete or N/A

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
status_solution="complete"
```

With

```
OR( status_solution="complete", status_solution="N/A" )
```

And the same for the other OR.

Answer (score 0):

using the following calculated field formula:

=IF(AND(status_finance="complete",status_cnl="complete",OR(status_solution="complete", status_solution="N/A"),OR(status_hr="complete", status_hr="N/A" )),"complete","initial")